# Best practice to check user access rights in RBAC

Tags: php, rbac

in my application I want to start with role based access control, but I dont know best practice for check if loged user has access right. On page I have some blocks where some user role can edit, but another can only view, and for third role is this block invisible.

my present code looks like this:

```
if (role=="admin") {
   full access
} elseif (role=="user") {
   only display content without editing option
} else {
   // not loged or user role with limited access
   no content display
}
```

but when I have on page 5 to 10 this blocks it is very unworkable to create a lot of this IF statements.
Is there some best practice to checking user roles without using IFs?

Thanks a lot and sorry my english.

Comment: what content are you displaying? is it taken from a database?

Comment: yes.. content is displaying from database, all access roles are defined in database.

Answer (score 2):

Give roles numbers:

```
const ACCESS_NONE   = 0;
const ACCESS_USER   = 1;
const ACCESS_ADMIN  = 2;
const ACCESS_ROOT   = 4;
```

Note I'm using powers of two, that way even if a user has all the accesses before a certain one, it still won't be bigger (NONE + USER + ADMIN < ROOT).

Now, all you have to do is

```
if ($access >= ACCESS_ADMIN) { //admin+ only content
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. in applicatin it looks like this.. user is logged, in session is his role number and after that all block is checking if this role can display, or edit this block. Some role can only display content but another role can see form for editing this content. And I want to find some effective way to checking it.